# BigTable data schema design

Tags: nosql, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I am learning about BigTable, and trying to design a good schema for it

user there will be an ID(unique), in time this user will receive many events(these events don't have an Id, only the timestamp is unique). Also I want to use bigTable garbage collection to expire a event.

The query that I will be use and won't change in the future:

1/ getAllEventsByUserId (order events by timestamp)

2/ getEventDetailByUserIdAndTimestamp

I'm confusing about the row key. Should I just `user_id` as row key or `user_id#timestmap`

Base on what I know, using just `user_id` can get very good performance for query 1 but I don't know if it bad for query 2. If `user_id#timestamp` then query 2 is very good but will query 1 have to scan with pattern which will cost a lot resource

Answer (score 2):

As [each row key must be unique](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design?hl=en#:%7E:text=Each%20row%20key%20must%20be%20unique), `user_id` can not be your row key. Hence, you should go with `user_id#timestmap` instead

Answer (score 0):

How many events do you expect per user? How large do you think a row can get if you were to write all events for a given user into a single row?

If each row will be < 100 MB (rows could be larger but not recommended), you can make userid the key and use timestamps for each event since in Bigtable every cell is defined by 3 identifiers, rowkey + column (family+qualifier) and timestamp. Timestamps also sort reverse chronologically to make it faster to get the most recent N items within a row and can be used for garbage collection.